# What product is better: ADFSv2, Ping Identity, CS Siteminder?

Tags: saml, adfsv2, sso

I'm comparing different STS's for claims based authentication and am trying when it's appropriate to use each one.

It appears that ADFSv2 should be used in all Windows Environments.  Ping and Siteminder are more for the Unix side... although a sales rep said Ping was better for Windows, I didn't really understand "why"

Any comparative information is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

We are in the middle of doing SSO where I'm at right now.  We couldn't get Site Minder to let us *pay* for a developer license; they literally didn't return the numerous calls we made begging to use their software (one of our clients was using it and we figured it would be the easiest path).

We went with Ping Identity's Pingfederate product (or is it the other way around)?

The documentation isn't amazing, but it's working for us.  When you can get past first-level support, they have been very helpful and getting us going.  Your application will be dependent upon their APIs, but your application will also support numerous open standards for SSO.  They also have consulting available to do the heavy lifting if you have the budget.

Comment: Do you mind me dropping you an email regarding SSO as it is warping my brain? If you drop me an email at peanutsmonkey@gmail.com, I'll reply in response.

Answer (score 1):

Which STS you choose should really be based on your near term as well as strategic requirements.  For the record, PingFederate works very well in a Windows environment.  Ping Identity actually has many, many Windows IT shops successfully deploying PingFederate.  So whether or not you are a Windows shop shouldn't be the sole determiner.

You might want to consider the range of applications that need to integrate into your SSO ecosystem.  That includes both identity management products such as Active Directory, OAM, SiteMinder, as well as relying applications.  Your SSO solution should be selected based on those integration needs.

Ping Identity did a ton of work this summer to ensure that we are well aligned with ADFSv2/WCF/WIF environments.  Along with that, PingFederate provides very rich integration into many existing identity management products, directories, and databases.  There are also several language kits for embedding SAML, WS-Trust, and WS-Federation single sign-on into .Net, Java, and PHP.

Another key differentiator between PingFederate and other SSO/Federation products is the speed and ease with which a PingFederate ecosystem can be established.  Generally, PingFederate customers get up in running in hours or day.  Not weeks or months.

Also note that Ping Identity offers a cloud based solution, PingConnect, for those companies that are not ready or don't need to invest in a full scale on premise SSO/Federation solution.

Answer (score 0):

How to download Siteminder policy server for windows 2012 server and which version i have to download.

while downloading a hotfix i am getting this message>This solution belongs to a product for which you do not have an active license.